# Error-2 : End kernel Panic while booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel, bios

After running `sudo apt-get -f install` command at terminal and downloaded about **351 MB** of fixes, I **restarted** Ubuntu 16.04 OS but after selecting "Ubuntu" From **Windows Boot Menu** (Default OS : *Windows 10*) and then **selecting ubuntu from GRUB menu**, screen **hanged** at purple-orange wallpaper - one which is shown in GRUB menu, **something like this image**:[Grub Boot loader Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmMAE.png) and **caps lock** key was continuously **blinking** .

I restarted by holding power key for 5 Seconds and then again selected "Ubuntu" from Windows Boot Loader and selected `Advanced Options` from GRUB Menu and then `recovery mode (I don't know  what's written after that)` and after in **DOS like screen** after all the commands were loaded automatically, an **error** was shown :

> > end Kernel Panic - not synced Requested init/sbin/upstart failed **(error-2)**

Please Help

> > PC Specs:
> >
> > Operating systems installed:
> >
> > Windows 10 64 bit ,Windows 8.1 64 bit , Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 bit
> >
> > Laptop has BIOS, not UEFI.
> >
> > **More Info**: [PC Specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IN3Ma.png) *screenshot taken from windows 8.1*

Thanks in advance

Comment: Reinstalled Ubuntu again!